# How can we detect if main() thread is dead but all threads() spawned are running?

Tags: java, process

As a part of execution of our linux based java application, main() creates threads.

We want to guard our application so that, if main() exits due to some unforeseen scenarios, all threads are to be killed and does not stay as zombies.

Questions
- Can a main thread die in a different manner other a clean exit or an exception
If we catch any RuntimeException, in main(), and 
wait for all threads to complete, are we safe ? No question of zombies at all ?

- If there is such a possibility, how do the other threads detect if our main() thread is dead,
- If we found a way to detect, how do we terminate all the threads that main created.

solutions inside application(implemented within java code) or solutions outside application(shell scripts) or a mixture of both, anything is fine.

Thoughts ?

Comment: Stopping `Thread`s in Java ain't altogether that easy - they need to be _stoppable_ - i.e. have some sort of `keepRunning` flag or be interruptable. Given that that is the case you can simply use an [`UncaughtExceptionHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler)) on the main `Thread` to stop the others.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Thread.setDaemon(true)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon%28boolean%29) for the threads you create. When the main thread exits, so will those threads. See the following test program:

```
public class TestThreads {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t = new MyThread();
        t.start();
    }
}   

class MyThread extends Thread {    
    public MyThread() {
         setDaemon(true);
    }    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Sleeping");
                sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you run it as is, the program will terminate almost immediately. If you comment out the `setDaemon(true);` line, it will block waiting for the thread to terminate, which will never happen in this scenario.

Comment: Thread.setDeamon(true) will only make it worse because we are designating threads to run as deamons even after main() dies. We do not want it and are exactly trying to avoid it. If main() dies, all threads that it created should die. Each thread can detect that main() is crashed and voluntarily die or an external process can detect that main() is dead and force kills all threads created

Comment: @smc that is exactly what `setDaemon` does. Read the documentation that this answer links to before posting uninformed and incorrect comments.

Comment: @smc I am not sure what you mean. Deamon threads will be forced to stop when there will be no non-deamon threads left (like main thread). Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: @BoristheSpider So does a parent-child kind of relationship exists between main() thread and all threads that it creates ?        update: I was thinking that: main() was just another thread to jvm, like all the threads main() spawns ? and deamon is a concept that links jvm and a given thread, rather than main() and a given thread.  Pls correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @mavroprovato Thanks, After some reading, now I understood what you said.

Answer (score 0):

As long as there are some non-daemon threads running, JVM will not exit. Once all non-daemon thread terminate, JVM exits, no matter how many daemon threads are still running. All the daemon threads that are still running are force terminated.